# C++ class copy constructor has no matching function

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, constants

I am trying to write a class Core, it's member variable is a pointer. The copy constructor is `Core(Core& x)` instead of `Core(const Core& x)`.

Core has a member function `Core Core::new_core (int * ptr)`, the code has a problem when I try to construct `Core new_core= core.new_core(ptr);`, please see the code and error information below.

```
#include<iostream>

class Core
{
    private:
    int* a;

    public:
    Core(int* in) {a=in;}
    Core(Core& x) {a = x.data();}

    inline const int * data() const {return a;}
    inline       int * data()       {return a;}

    Core new_core (int * ptr)
    {
        Core b(ptr);
        return b;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ptr[3]= {1,2,3};
    Core core(ptr);
    Core new_core= core.new_core(ptr);
    cout<< new_core.data() <<endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Error information:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cpp:30:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘Core::Core(Core)’
>
> ```
> Core new_core= core.new_core(ptr);
>                                  ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:30:37: note: candidates are:
>
> main.cpp:12:6: note: Core::Core(Core&)
>
> ```
>  Core(Core& x) { a = x.data() ;}
>  ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:12:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Core’ to >‘Core&’
>
> main.cpp:10:6: note: Core::Core(int*)
>
> ```
>  Core(int* in) {a=in;}
>  ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:10:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Core’ to 
>   ‘int*’

I can easily fix the problem by replacing

```
Core(Core& x) { a = x.data() ;}
```

to

```
Core(const Core& x) { a = const_cast<int* > ( x.data() ) ;},
```

is there a better way to solve the problem without using const_cast?

I want to keep `int* a` private, and keep following two lines:

```
inline const int * data() const {return a;}
inline       int * data()       {return a;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on what you want this class to do. Given that it is only referencing external data, does it make sense for `int * data() ` not to be `const`? i.e. `int * data()  const;`.

Comment: Thank you,  juanchopanza. I am make a too general example. In my real application, Core is a derived class,  const int * data()  const is from base class, which I can not change. I guess I have to use Core(const Core& x) to solve the problem?

Comment: Your problem is that a non-const rvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary. But an rvalue reference can. There was an answer (now deleted) that was almost right...

Comment: By the way, If I use: `Core core_a(ptr);` `Core core_b( core_a);`, the code will works fine. Why I can not use `Core new_core( core.new_core(ptr) );` ?

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `new_core` returns a `Core` which is a temporary.  When you use it in

```
Core new_core= core.new_core(ptr);
```

The compiler calls the copy constructor  but it cannot bind to that temporary since it takes a reference.  To fix this we can change the copy constructor to take a `const Core&` which can bind to the temporary and allow you to make a copy.

In this example to get around the `const` and the use of`const_cast`  we can access the class member directly like:

```
Core(const Core& x) : a(x.a) {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really help. I have one more question, in my real example, Core is a template drived class, and `int * a` is in template based class. When I need to access `a`, I always need to use `this->a`, it looks like I can not use: `Core(const Core& x) : this->a(x.a) {}`.

Comment: @HaoShi This sounds like the base class needs to have a proper copy constructor.  If you could provide a [mcve] in your question I may be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks NathanOliver! I see, I can solve the problem by writing a proper copy constructor in base class.